# Does using the Holy Weapon spell to create a burst of radiance end the spell entirely?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does using the *holy weapon* spell to create a burst of radiance end the spell entirely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, it ends the spell.

The [Holy Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/holy-weapon) spell description (XGtE, p. 157) says:

> As a bonus action on your turn, you can **dismiss** this spell and cause
> the weapon to emit a burst of radiance.

Dismissing a spell ends that spell.